# Spark Java: Failed to load class

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle

Spark application is build by the following gradle script:

```
 plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'application'
     }

 group = 'com.example.fileutil'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

application {
      mainClass = 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
}

jar {
       duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
       project.configurations.getByName("implementation").setCanBeResolved(true)
       manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
                }

 from { configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
// dependencies and repositories
```

And trying to run this spark application by:

```
  spark-submit --class "com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication" --queue default --deploy-mode client --master local --files cluster.properties hdfs_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And receive the following error:

```
  Failed to load class com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication.
```

FilePrepareApplication is located at build/classes/main/com/example/fileutil/

What am I doing wrong?